# Sqlalchemy sometimes can not get data

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, openstack

I have a database named `weixin_db` and there is a table named `nvi_instance` in it. This is detail :

```
mysql> desc instance;
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| guest_uuid   | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| logical_ipv4 | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| logical_ipv6 | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I use this to connect database:

```
def get_engine():
    global engine
    global conn
    if engine:
        if not conn:
            conn = engine.connect()
        return (engine, conn)

    conn_str = ''.join((conf["db_dialect"], "://", conf["db_user"], ":", conf["db_pwd"], "@",
                    conf["db_host"], ":", conf["db_port"], "/", conf["db_name"]))
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(conn_str)
    conn = engine.connect()
    return (engine, conn)
```

And this is configuration:

```
[db]
db_dialect = mysql
db_host = localhost
db_port = 3306
db_name = weixin_db
db_user = root
db_pwd = 9f71f05812f44553
```

When I use `sel_nvi_ip` to get data from the below code, SOMETIMES I can not get data, while sometimes I can get data from database:

```
class Nvi_Instance(object):
"""
inter_clouds
"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.engine, self.conn = get_engine()

    def sel_nvi_ipv4(self, guest_uuid):
        s =   sqlalchemy.select([weixinverify.c.logical_ipv4]).where(weixinverify.c.guest_uuid == guest_uuid)
        return self.conn.execute(s)

    def sel_nvi_ipv6(self, guest_uuid):
        s =       sqlalchemy.select([weixinverify.c.logical_ipv6]).where(weixinverify.c.guest_uuid == guest_uuid)
        return self.conn.execute(s)
```

The under code is call **sel_nvi_ipv4 and sel_nvi_ipv6**:

```
        value = {}
        from horizon.conf import nvi_db
        nvi = nvi_db.Nvi_Instance()

        value['id'] = 0
        try:
            value['ipv4'] = nvi.sel_nvi_ipv4(id).fetchone().values()[0]
            value['ipv6'] = nvi.sel_nvi_ipv6(id).fetchone().values()[0]
        except Exception as e:
            value['ipv4'] = None
            value['ipv6'] = None
        return {'getip': value}
```

And the exception `e` is :

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'values'
```

Does my configuration has problem or something goes wrong ???
Everything goes well after I do `service openstack-nova-api`. But after a few minutes , `nvi.sel_nvi_ip(id).fetchone()` returns `None` rather than data from database. There is anything goes wrong ? Could someone tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer:**

Your function get_engine returns tuple of engine and connection:

```
def get_engine():
    # ....
    return (engine, conn)
```

But in the Nvi_Instance you didn't unpack this tuple:

```
class Nvi_Instance(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = get_engine()   # self.conn == (engine, conn), not just conn !!!

    def sel_nvi_ip(self, guest_uuid):
        # s = ...
        return self.conn.execute(s)
        # You try to execute query on tuple, not on connection!
```

Then you call it in try-except and swallow any exception silently (don't do that):

```
try:
    value['ipv4'],value['ipv6'] = nvi.sel_nvi_ip(id).fetchone()        
except:
    # Here you catch: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'execute'
    value['ipv4'] = None
    value['ipv6'] = None
return {'getip': value}
```

So you get None, instead of data from DB.

**Additional update:**

It'll better to move checking of returned value from client code into Nvi_Instance:

```
def sel_nvi_ip(self, guest_uuid):
    s = sqlalchemy.select([weixinverify.c.logical_ipv4, weixinverify.c.logical_ipv6]).where(weixinverify.c.guest_uuid == guest_uuid)
    result = self.conn.execute(s).first()
    return result.values() if result is not None else (None, None)
```

Then in client code you have to write just:

```
value['ipv4'], value['ipv6'] = nvi.sel_nvi_ip(id)
return {'getip': value}
```

Comment: @changzhi could you provide more info about your problem. You wrote "SOMETIMES I can not get data, while sometimes I can get data from database." How often it happens? I also see that you query particular record (i.e. weixinverify.c.guest_uuid == guest_uuid) When such type of records are created? May be there is a race condition and the issue in the application logic, not in the SQLAlchemy config.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I edited the above code following your advice. I still have a question have to ask you. It seems that there is no use  about **self.engine**. And in Sqlalchemy, if I want to execute a sql code, `return self.conn.execute(s)` or `return self.engine.execute(s)` ???

Comment: I have changed my code . Please read it in detail again. Thank you !

Comment: Ok, now it seems None comes from DB. Could you provide detailed log of SQLAlchemy. See for details: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/engines.html?highlight=logging#configuring-logging

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45189/discussion-between-dmitry-vakhrushev-and-changzhi)

Comment: It seems that everything goes okay after I use `value['ipv4'] = nvi.sel_nvi_ipv4(id).fetchone().values()[0]  value['ipv6'] = nvi.sel_nvi_ipv6(id).fetchone().values()[0]` instead of `value['ipv4'],value['ipv6'] = nvi.sel_nvi_ip(id).fetchone()` . But I don't know why. Does it have a relationship between `self.conn` and `self.engine` ? I have no use `self.engine` with any sqlalchemy instances. Thank you !

Comment: @changzhi, you missed values() in "value['ipv4'],value['ipv6'] = nvi.sel_nvi_ip(id).fetchone()" So that's why it doesn't work. I hope, I helped you to solve your issue.